# Tengo problemas al clonar mi proyecto de a un repositorio local de Git

Tags: git

Hola estoy trabajando con **Git**, y estoy utilizando **Git-bash** cuando quiero clonar con el comando $ git clone (directorio local) el **Git** me responde con un mensaje de alerta que dice :"parece que a clonado un repositorio vació", ajunto una imagen de como lo hice

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes agregar el comando git que estas usando? o lo que creo que necesitas hacer es una nueva branch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asegúrate que en tu repositorio que quieres clonar tengas **commit**eados tus cambios.

Para esto, dirígete por terminal a la ruta del repositorio que quieres clonar e ingresa el comando:

```
git status
```

te debería salir un mensaje:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
...
```

Donde listará los archivos que están sin versionar, seguramente porque acabas de iniciar git o porque hiciste nuevos cambios. Entonces lo que necesitas hacer es guardar estos cambios primero agregándolos al commit que vas a crear con el siguiente comando:

```
git add .
```

Que agregará al commit todos los archivos con modificaciones que estén al nivel de tu carpeta .git(que se creó cuando iniciaste git) en adelante. Una vez agregado los archivos debes realizar el commit con un mensaje:

```
git commit -m "my message"
```

"my message" es el mensaje que le estás colocando al commit que acabas de hacer, ahora para confirmar que no tengas archivos sin versionar ejecuta el commando:

```
git status
```

Que debería darte el mensaje:

```
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Ahora si puedes clonar localmente tu repositorio normalmente:

```
git clone RUTA/A/MYREPOSITORY RUTA/A/MYNEWREPOSITORY
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el error está en que no haz puesto la dirección del repositorio que quieres clonar.

Tu tienes:

```
$git clone <directorio_local_nuevo>
```

deberías tener:

```
$git clone https://github.com/usuario/proyecto.git <directorio_local_nuevo>
```